# jQuery code works incorrectly on Android phone

Tags: android, jquery

I have this code running fine when tested on a PC (Win10 x64) on jFiddle site, but once I run it in Android phone in the actual webside code, it works incorrectly, thinking the state of css "display" that is changed upon clicking corresponding object (.navbutton) is still "none" tho visually it already is set to correct "inline-block" making it still visible although it should make it disappear when clicked 2nd time (it cyclically changes display state from none to inline-block upon clicking the object).

```
jQuery('.navbutton').click(function(e) {
  if(jQuery('#menuContainer').css('display') == 'none') {
    jQuery('#menuContainer').css('display', 'inline-block');
  } else {
    jQuery('#menuContainer').css('display', 'none');
  }
  e.stopPropagation();
})
jQuery('*:not(".navbutton")').click(function(e) {
  jQuery('#menuContainer').css('display', 'none');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9tnj2pLe/

But if I omit the 2nd part of the code like this (no jQuery('*:not(".navbutton")')), it works, but now it lacks the function of closing the menu once clicked anywhere outside it:

```
jQuery('.navbutton').click(function(e) {
  if(jQuery('#menuContainer').css('display') == 'none') {
    jQuery('#menuContainer').css('display', 'inline-block');
  } else {
    jQuery('#menuContainer').css('display', 'none');
  }
  e.stopPropagation();
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/58hdf26z/

I tested it in Android Chrome and Android Firefox browsers.

Does anyone know where is the problem that it does not work on Android in its Chrome webbrowser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I just find out myself by experimenting a lot that the reason was that there are 3 thin span objects inside the .navbutton, and if it happens that it was so small the finger on Android browser happens to click directly on them - as there is also a gap between them - the code was not fired up.

Thus once added another :not() into the jQuery selector for the specific span objects it works!

```
jQuery('.navbutton').click(function(e) {
  if(jQuery('#menuContainer').css('display') == 'none') {
    jQuery('#menuContainer').css('display', 'inline-block');
  } else {
    jQuery('#menuContainer').css('display', 'none');
  }
  e.stopPropagation();
})
jQuery('*:not(".navbutton"):not(".navbutton span")').click(function(e) {
  jQuery('#menuContainer').css('display', 'none');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dz8pefgs/